# KeyError in Doc2Vec model even when min_count set to 1 during training

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm using doc2vec with a corpus of about 1 million titles. To train the corpus, I'm using the following code:

```
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(min_count=1, window=10, size=300, workers=4)
model.build_vocab(corpus)
for epoch in range(10):
    model.train(corpus)
```

Everything seems to train properly and I am able to infer a vector using titles.most_similar.

I encounter a problem, however, when I try to use the vectors. It seems as though some documents are missing from the final model! I.e.:

```
model.docvecs['SENT_157000']
```

> KeyError: 'SENT_157000'

I checked the gensim forum and stackoverflow and the only suggestion I could find was to ensure that the min_count = 1. I did that but I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `gensim`'s `Doc2Vec` [documentation](http://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/), input to `Doc2Vec`  should be an iterator of `LabeledSentence` objects.

Your `corpus` variable needs to be constructed as follows:

```
class LabeledLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def __iter__(self):
        for uid, line in enumerate(open(self.filename)):
            yield LabeledSentence(words=line.split(), labels=['SENT_%s' % uid])


corpus = LabeledLineSentence(filename)
```

followed by

```
model.train(corpus)
```